# Python - Function to remove stopwords from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, series

I have the below data, stored as a Series (called **data_counts**), showing words in the Index and count values in the '0' column. Series contains 30k words however I use the below as an example :

```
Index      |    0

the        |    3425
American   |    431 
a          |    213 
I          |    124
hilarious  |    53
Mexican    |    23
is         |    2
```

I'd like to convert the words in the Index to lowercase and remove the stopwords using NLTK. I have seen some examples on SO achieving this using 'lambdas' (see below example for a dataframe), however I'd like to do this by running a DEF function instead (I am a Python newbie and this seems to me the easiest to understand).

```
df['Index'] = df['Index'].apply(lambda stop_remove: [word.lower() for word in stop_remove.split() if word not in stopwords])
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: lambdas are (tiny) functions. I don't think your question is currently clearly stated. could you provide some examples of what lambdas you've seen do the work, and what syntax you wish to achieve.

Comment: `data_counts[~data_counts.index.str.lower().isin(stopwords)]` ?

Comment: Chris, this works really well! Just for my own understanding, what is the '~' performing here?

Comment: it is a `NOT` operator essentially. it reverses bool values

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to `define` your own function you can use `.apply` after that rowwise:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['the', 'American', 'a', 'I', 'hilarious', 'Mexican', 'is'],
                  data={ 0:[3425, 431, 213, 124, 53, 23, 2]})

# Clean up dataframe and convert words to lowercase
df['words'] = df.index.str.lower()
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Define our function to remove stopwords
def remove_stopwords(word):
    if word not in stopwords.words('english'):
        return word
    else:
        return ''

# Apply the function to our words column to clean up.
df['words_clean'] = df.words.apply(remove_stopwords)
print(df)
      0      words words_clean
0  3425        the            
1   431   american    american
2   213          a            
3   124          i            
4    53  hilarious   hilarious
5    23    mexican     mexican
6     2         is
```